# Winforms datagridviewbuttoncell restrict mouse hover and click event to change background color of a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a dgv with button columns and want to change button cell color on click (let's say from green to red). However when I hover mouse pointer on a cell it changes its background color to transparent (matching bg color of a grid), and on click it changes it's color to a third one. Button's flatstyle is set to flat, all DefaultGridStyle colors' options are set to green. How can I prevent button cell color to change its color on mouse hover and click?

I have tried redefining CellMouseEnter and CellMouseDown events:

```
private void dgv_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor;
}

private void dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor;
}
```

However, picking a different color changes cell's border color and background color stays transparent.

Comment: Try a Click Event with a bool if red then make green on click and if green make red on click Using Down and Enter is more than likely the issue

Comment: not working since the color is not the same the moment it clicked (it's not green when mouse is hovered or clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (and the additional comment below it) indicate that you want the color to change on `CellMouseDown`. It appears that what keeps this from happening is that the cell becomes **selected** the "moment it's clicked". So, if you don't *also* change the `cell.Style.SelectionBackColor` then it will probably not behave the way you want it to. When I tested it, that small change seems to make it work the way you describe.

[image: screenshot]

---

Here, when mouse goes to the down state, this method not only sets the `cell.Style.SelectionBackColor`, it also washes it out a little for some visual feedback.

```
private void onCellMouseDown(object? sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Color)].Index == e.ColumnIndex &&  e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        Color newColor;
        var cell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        switch (cell.Style.BackColor.Name) 
        {
            case nameof(Color.LightGreen): newColor = Color.LightSalmon; break;
            case nameof(Color.LightSalmon): newColor = Color.LightBlue; break;
            case nameof(Color.LightBlue):
            default:
                newColor = Color.LightGreen;
                break;

        }
        Recordset[e.RowIndex].Color = 
            cell.Style.BackColor = newColor;

        const int OFFSET = 40;
        cell.Style.SelectionBackColor =
            Color.FromArgb(
                Math.Min(255, newColor.R + OFFSET),
                Math.Min(255, newColor.G + OFFSET),
                Math.Min(255, newColor.B + OFFSET)
        );
        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

When the mouse comes back up, pull the real `Style.BackColor` and transfer it to `Style.SelectionBackColor`.

```
private void onCellMouseUp(object? sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Color)].Index == e.ColumnIndex && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        var cell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        cell.Style.SelectionBackColor =
            cell.Style.BackColor;
        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

And I should mention that I set this column to `ReadOnly` because multiple mouse clicks are going to enter `Edit` mode otherwise and you might have a new problem to deal with.